# running xamarin.forms on IOS simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to run my application on IOS simulator, but i dont have mac machine. I have an iphone 7plus with version IOS 12.2
can anyone help me find a free mac machine or how i should buy virtual mac machine just for testing my app on ios simulator.
thank you

Comment: Well, I would suggest you get your self a mac machine, DO NOT use or create an Apple VM as that is against T&C of apple, without it, you cannot do anything sorry.

Comment: "can anyone help me find a free mac machine". Sorry but this is a red flag for closing the question hopefully other people will vote too instead of answering or giving comments. It is in your best interest to understand that this approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the license macOS license (section *2B*):

> you are granted a
>   limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial use, one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly on each **Apple-branded computer** [...]
>
> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within **virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer** you own [...]
>
> [emphasis mine]

This makes clear that you are not allowed to run macOS on a non-Mac computer. This rules out a virtual machine running on your Windows. *(At least officially - there may be ways to run a Hackintosh in a VM, but I have never tried. You could also try to run a cheap PC as a Hackintosh, but YMMV. **And beware:** IANAL, hence I cannot really tell you about the legal implications of breaking the license agreement. If you wanted to do it, consider consulting [law.se](http://law.stackexchange.com), or a professional.)*

I have never heard about services that provide free macs, and really ... why should they. You could opt to use a service like [macincloud](https://www.macincloud.com/), but they charge starting from $20 per month. Assuming that you can acquire a used decent mac mini or macBook Pro for $250 or so, you would not really save any money by using macincloud, if you are using it for more than a year (it could still be a viable alternative for the beginning). Plus, you have full control over the system having your own mac.

Comment: Thank you everybody. as i understand from your comment the only way is to buy a mac machine. bad news.